# In php, a string concatenation (with a string obtained by a function call) is disordered. Why?

Tags: php, string, wordpress, concatenation

This:

```
echo '<br>';
$author_single = sprintf( '/%s/single.php', 'francadaval' );
echo ( $author_single );

echo '<br>';
$author_single = sprintf( '/%s/single.php', the_author_meta( 'nickname') );
echo ( $author_single );

echo '<br>';
$nick = the_author_meta( 'nickname');
$author_single = sprintf( '/%s/single.php', $nick );
echo ( $author_single );
```

show this:

```
/francadaval/single.php
francadaval//single.php
francadaval//single.php
```

I saw that the concatenation order is affected by the function call so I tried to use a intermediate variable but it doesn't work.

Using dot operator instead of `sprintf` or with `"/{$nick}/single.php"` does the same.

The function `the_author_meta` is a Wordpress function to get data from the author of a post and in this case must returns the author's nickname ('*francadaval*').

How can I get this working so `$author_single` results to be '/francadaval/single.php' using the function call for the nickname of the author?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't totally agree with your output `sprintf` would not remove `/` in front of the output

Comment: @Baba: `sprintf` is not removing the `/`. Read my answer below for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`get_the_author_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) instead of `the_author_meta`.

- `the_author_meta` **display** author meta
- `get_the_author_meta` **return** author meta

Answer (score 2):

It appears that instead of returning a value, the `the_author_meta()` function is outputting the value.

So what is actually happening is this:

```
echo '<br>';
$author_single = sprintf( '/%s/single.php', 'francadaval' );
echo ( $author_single );
```

Outputs `/francadaval/single.php` as expected.

```
echo '<br>';
$author_single = sprintf( '/%s/single.php', the_author_meta( 'nickname') );
echo ( $author_single );
```

The inner function `the_author_meta` runs first, so outputs `francadaval` and returns `null`. `sprintf` is then run with `null` as the second argument, returning `//single.php`. Then the `echo` statment appends `//single.php` to the output (which now already has `francadaval`) producing the result:
`francadaval//single.php`

```
echo '<br>';
$nick = the_author_meta( 'nickname');
$author_single = sprintf( '/%s/single.php', $nick );
echo ( $author_single );
```

Is similar to the above scenario, you've just split the function calls into separate lines.

As soju states the correct function to use in this case is `get_the_author_meta()` which returns the value as expected.

So the correct code is:

```
echo '<br>';
$author_single = sprintf( '/%s/single.php', get_the_author_meta( 'nickname') );
echo ( $author_single );
```